# 500 internal error when customer/account/create posts a details

Tags: customer-account

I have been recently assigned to a Magento website that runs on version 2.3.7. The error of this site is a **PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function create()  vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php on line 1235**. It happens on **customer/account/createpost/** after the customer has filled in the form.

Please help.
[image]

The error message that comes up is;

[image]

Comment: Line 1235 doesn't have a call to a create() method in Magento 2.3.7. [See Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.7/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php#L1235). There is not enough information for anyone to go off of. You will need to provide some example code from around line 1235.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below command and check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it but it is still crashing

Answer (score 0):

Custom Module is affecting.

Disable Custom Module and check.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/190705)

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi i have facing a same issue with many times of custom module.

Comment: But the information you have given is not sufficient for accepting as an answer in this platform please add some more information that what all steps you have taken to resolve this! or how custom module is affecting this

Comment: Thanks. Tried but the problem persists.